# When trying to edit a configurable product I'm getting VariationMatrix error Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, magento2.4.2, configurable-product-options

I am using Magento 2.4.2 community when I try to edit a configurable product I am getting the below in my store. How to fix it.

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/Type/VariationMatrix.php
> on line 47
>
> Exception in
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check whether the associated product linked have the configurable attributes first. If by any chance it is removed from the attribute set it might be the cause.